I can't add admin HD properly in Roblox Studio
In general, when I add it to the workspace, it is added, but after I  install it, the commands do not work. It works in another place.
I tried deleting and adding back the pack, reopening the project and restarting Roblox studio, but it didn't help.
How can i fix this?

Drag the pack in the ServerScriptServer folder. Make sure none of the scripts are disabled. Make sure you have the right pack, some are scams. Search HD ADMIN in the explorer and delete anything with the name.  Make sure no parts have the name HD ADMIN. Reinstall the pack. (You have already done some of this.) If that doesn't work, enable API services via Basic Settings, thus allowing the pack to access the services it needs! I hope this helped!

@den4ik_here np!
